# Django, model filter and order by other foreignkey model

Tags: django, filter

model1:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
```

model2:

```
class TagConnect(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey("category.Tag", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to get top 5 Tag object by count of TagConnect object that has created in recent 24 hours.

The more TagConnect object exists, the tag is more likely on high priority.

If tag "rabbit" has 2 TagConnect in 24 hours and "horse" has 10 TagConnect but those are not in 24 hours,
"rabbit" has more high priority.

Maybe it will be like..

```
Tag.objects.order_by(tag_connect_in_24hours)[:5]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get top 5 `Tag` object by count of `TagConnect` object that has created in recent 24 hours.

You can first filter the related model, then perform a `Count`, and then order by that `Count` and take the first five objects, so:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import Count
from django.utils.timezone import now

Tag.objects.filter(
    tagconnect__created__gte=now()-timedelta(days=1)
).annotate(
    nconnect=Count('tagconnect')
).order__by('-nconnect')[:5]
```

Since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), you can use [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) to avoid aggregating twice: one for the extra attribute the `Tag`s will use, and one to `ORDER BY`. By using `alias(…)` we only do this in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import Count
from django.utils.timezone import now

Tag.objects.filter(
    tagconnect__created__gte=now()-timedelta(days=1)
).alias(
    nconnect=Count('tagconnect')
).order__by('-nconnect')[:5]
```